# How to keep table elements fixed with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core

I want the tags inside the table to be fixed when printing. The code I wrote works well in View, but when printing in JavaScript, if one of the columns is large, the rest of the columns go in the middle but I want everyone to stay on top I used position: fixed but the table crashed.

```
<script>


    function printDiv() {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('table');
        var htmlToPrint = '' +
            '<style type="text/css">' +
            'table th, table td,table tr {' +
            'font-family:B Nazanin;'+
            'border:0.1em solid #000;' +
              'text-align:center;' + 
            
            'font-size:14px;' +
            'padding:0.2em;' +
            '}' +
            '</style>';


        htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
        newWin = window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }



</script>
```

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what the problem is. Would you like all the columns to have the same width?

Comment: I want the contents of the columns to start from the top

Comment: But as you see in the picture, the contents of some of the columns come in the middle when printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `vertical-align: top;` to make the content in each cell. display at the top.

```
<style>
            .table-bd{
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border: none;
                width: 200px;
            }
            .table-bd td{
                border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                word-break:break-all;
                width: 50px;
                height: 80px;
                vertical-align: top;
            }
        </style>

<table class="table-bd">
            <tr>
                <td>asdfasdfasdf</td>
                <td>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>asdfasdfasdf</td>
                <td>qwerqwerqwerqwerqwer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>erwtewyrettyrety</td>
                <td>tyuirtyiuiytugfhdfgh</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

[image]